# Memcached Issues with Laravel 5.5 as Cache Driver

Tags: php, laravel, caching, memcached

I've been scratching my head on this all day and scouring the internet for any help, but I have not found it, so here's my problem:

I have an existing web application using Laravel 5.5 and I want to set up caching using Memcached. I would use Redis but since Laravel doesn't allow Redis to be used as a broadcast driver and cache driver, I'm stuck with Memcached. I have created a new Laravel project to test caching before implementing it into my existing project. **So here is the issue I am having...**

I can store data in the cache, and immediately call the `Cache::get('mykey');` on the same request and the data is returned. If I comment the `Cache::put('mykey', $myData, 10);` and then refresh the page, no data! I have checked the configurations over and over again, and I don't see any errors. **Something I should point out:** If I run `composer dumpautoload -o` then the cache displays the data for a few requests, then returns null as it has 99% of the previous attempts. Here is how I have tested.

```
// This queries the database MOST of the time
$value = Cache::rememberForever('users', function() {
    \Log::info('database query');
    return Todo::all();
});

// This almost always returns null
Cache::put('todos', Todo::all(), 10);
$todos  = (Cache::has('todos') ? Cache::get('todos') : null);

// Oddly, this will return true a few times also        
$isAdded = Cache::add('todos', Todo::all(), 10);
if($isAdded)
    \Log::info('Added to cache');
```

I have verified that my memcached PHP extension is properly installed and that it's listening on port 11211, so I believe it may be a Laravel configuration. I was using sasl authentication but I have disabled that and that made no difference. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

**UPDATE:**

```
'memcached' => [
        'driver' => 'memcached',
        'persistent_id' => env('MEMCACHED_PERSISTENT_ID'),
        'sasl' => [
            env('MEMCACHED_USERNAME'),
            env('MEMCACHED_PASSWORD'),
        ],
        'options' => [
            // Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT  => 2000,
        ],
        'servers' => [
            [
                'host' => env('MEMCACHED_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'port' => env('MEMCACHED_PORT', 11211),
                'weight' => 100,
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: I should also add that if I switch my cache driver to "file" then everything works as it should

Comment: What do you mean by `my memcached PHP extension is properly installed and it's listening on port 11211`? You need a memcached server that is listening on port 11211, the memcached PHP extension is only the client. Also, could you post your memcached config in `config/cache.php`?

Comment: @SaschaTrifunovic, I updated my OP with the `config/cache.php` file. Also, I have the memcached server installed as well as the `php-memcached` extension.

Comment: The configuration looks good. A few more questions: (1) did you set `CACHE_DRIVER=memcached`? (2) when you execute `php -m` do you see the memcached module loaded? (3) Can you run the memcached server in verbose mode (`memcached -vv`) and confirm the get and set commands actually arrive at the server?

Comment: @SaschaTrifunovic, I do have the `CACHE_DRIVER=memcached` set in the `.env` file and I also see the module loaded when I execute `php -m`. Also, I tried the `memcached -vv` command and ran the script to set and get cache data, but did not see anything new in the terminal. I uninstalled and reinstalled `memcached` and `php-memcached` and it seems to be working as expected now. The only thing I did different was not setting the `sasl2` authentication.

Comment: If it did not work with sasl enabled it could be that you did not have the username/password DB set up for the memached server. In that case you should have seen a failed authentication attempt in the output of `memcached -vv`. In any case, happy it is working now for you!

Comment: @SaschaTrifunovic, thank you for all your help!